# ¿Cómo habilitar Google Meet en google Calendar vía Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar

Resulta que en mi trabajo debemos cargar un volumen importante de actividades mensuales en Google Calendar (GC), por lo cual, gracias a Apps Script, ya se logró automatizar ese proceso y no ir uno por uno (lo cual nos demoraba unas horas).

No obstante, ha sido imposible lograr que cuando se cree el evento en GC se habilite la opción de crear el enlace a sesión de Google Meet. El código actualmente solamente crea el evento, pero luego hay que ir por cada evento habilitando esta opción.

Espero que me puedan ayudar y señalar en qué parte del código se debe colocar, siempre que ello sea posible. La idea es que en una columna se señale si se habilita o no Meet para el evento que está en la fila del archivo hoja de cálculo de Sheets.

A continuación presento el código que tengo...

```
function CrearEventosDesdeSheets() {
  var fila = 2
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Señalar el nombre de la hoja en donde están los datos de los eventos a cargar a Google Calendar
  var hoja = libro.getSheetByName('Eventos');

  for (fila; fila <= hoja.getLastRow(); fila++) {

    //Variables que contienen información desde la hoja de cálculo que contiene los eventos a crear.
    //hoja.getRange(fila, número de columna)
    var nameActividad = hoja.getRange(fila, 1).getValue();
    var fechaInicial = hoja.getRange(fila, 2).getValue();
    var fechaFinal = hoja.getRange(fila, 3).getValue();
    var ubicacion = hoja.getRange(fila, 4).getValue();
    var invitados = hoja.getRange(fila, 5).getValue();
    var description = hoja.getRange(fila, 6).getValue();

    //La siguiente variable es para que registre la información de la hoja de cálculo en el Calendario de Google.
    var evento = CalendarApp.createEvent(
      nameActividad, fechaInicial, fechaFinal,
      {
        location: ubicacion,
        description: description,
        guests: invitados,
        //Para enviar correo a las personas que se hayan invitado
        sendInvites: true
      });

    //Para que escriba en la hoja de cálculo un texto
    //Registra que la creación del evento fue hecha
    hoja.getRange(fila, 7).setValue('Hecho');

    //Registrar la Id del evento creado en Google Calendar en la hoja de cálculo.
    const id = evento.getId();
    hoja.getRange(fila, 8).setValue(id);


  }
}

// Hacer que aparezca un botón en la barra de herramientas y así sea más fácil la ejecución de este código.
function onOpen() {
  const menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Sumar_Al_Calendario');
  menu.addItem('Crear eventos en Calendario', 'CrearEventosDesdeSheets')
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado / intentado? [Según la doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events?hl=es-419), debes crear un evento, indicando la propiedad `conferenceData` en el mismo.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por comentar.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por comentar.  Estuve investigando, pero no encontraba información de cómo poder hacerlo. Al ver la documentación que señalas, veo que sí es posible, así que probaré con esa propiedad. Pronto comentaré el cómo me fue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y finalmente se logró el objetivo que al generar el evento a través de este método, habilitara el enlace de la videollamada de Google Meet.

No era necesario código, solo se debía de entrar en configuración del propio Calendario de Google y habilitar la opción que se muestra más abajo en la imagen.

[image: En configuraciones de Google Calendar se puede habilitar o deshabilitar la creación automática de sesiones Google Meet]

Una vez habilitado, todo funciona como debe.

Para el uso que necesito darle (crear muchas actividades virtuales), que los cree de forma automática es más que suficiente y de forma manual, elimino las que no lo necesitan (que son las menos).
De todos modos, agradezco a @A.Cedano por su disposición para encontrar solución al problema planteado.